# form_for issue GET request instead of patch

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have edit form for company as bellow in edit.html.erb

```
  <%= form_for([:dashboard , @company]  ) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :name , :class => "form-control"   %>
      <%= f.submit "Save" , :class => "btn btn-primary"%>
  <% end %>
```

and my companies_controller.rb

```
    def edit
     @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      # Update code
    end
```

and my routes.rb

```
   namespace :dashboard do
       resources :companies , only: [ :edit , :update ]
   end
```

The problem is when submit the form get the bellow error

```
   No route matches [GET] "/dashboard/companies/3"
```

Comment: You should add `:method => :get` in the `form_for`.

Comment: Why add :method => :get in the form_for , i want to issue patch request to update company data

Comment: can you post your code on `update` action?

Comment: Looks correct to me. What does `rake route` give ? Did you try without  the `dashboard` namespace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_for` accepts a post method by default.Here the `edit` action is `get` method,so your `form_for` should look like this

```
<%= form_for([:dashboard , @company],:html => {:method => :get }) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :name , :class => "form-control"   %>
      <%= f.submit "Save" , :class => "btn btn-primary"%>
  <% end %>
```

**OR**

You can do like this too

```
<%= form_for([:dashboard , @company] :url =>edit_dashboard_company_path(@company)) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :name , :class => "form-control"   %>
      <%= f.submit "Save" , :class => "btn btn-primary"%>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I want to update company data , i don't understand why form_for generate GET request not Patch request to Update company data

Comment: @AhmedShawky Because the form refers to edit action.